# React-Router V3 'dummy' or 'pass-through' route

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am using React Router v3 and I am trying to alter the browser's back-button functionality to close an open modal without moving backwards and retain the page on the background.  I accomplish this with the following code:

```
  componentDidMount() {
    browserHistory.push('modal');
    window.addEventListener('popstate', this.props.closeModal);
  }
  componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener('popstate', this.props.closeModal);
  }
```

This works as expected.  At the same time, I want to provide a catch-all route to display the home page component when the user tries to navigate to a route that is not defined. However, the code `<Route path="*" component=... />` requires that I specify a specific component.  When I push the `modal` route to the browserHistory stack, I get an error.  When I provide `<Route path="*" component=... />`, I lose the background behind the modal when the `modal` route is pushed to browserHistory.  Is there a way to define a catch-all route that renders the last component that was active or perhaps a better way to approach this problem?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: I don't remember, i no longer have access to that codebase.  Sorry!

Comment: Thanks for the reply btw